# context is giving me undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I am uncertain why after the initial load the values in context becomes undefined.

The way I have my context written up is:

```
export const ProductListContext = createContext({});

export const useListProductContext = () => useContext(ProductListContext);

export const ListProductContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [listProduct, setListProduct] = useState({
    images: [],
    title: "Hello",
  });
  return (
    <ProductListContext.Provider value={{ listProduct, setListProduct }}>
      {children}
    </ProductListContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

On the initial load of my component. I so get the listProduct to be correct as a `console.log` will produce

```
the list is Object {
  "images": Array [],
  "title": "Hello",
}
```

The problem is when I try to read `listProduct` again after it says it is undefined unless I save it to a `useState`. Any help on this is appreciated. The problem is within the `pickImage` function

```js
// Initial has all properties correctly
const { listProduct, setListProduct } = useListProductContext();
// Seems to work at all times when I save it here
const [product] = useState(listProduct);
console.log('the list product listed is ', listProduct);
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
      const {
        status,
      } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
    }
  })();
}, []);

const pickImage = async () => {
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 3],
    quality: 1,
    exif: true,
  });
  // PROBLEM - listProduct is undefined
  console.log('before copy it is ', listProduct);
  const listProduct = { ...product };
  console.log('the list is', listProduct);
  listProduct.images.push(result.uri);
  // listProduct.images.push(result.uri);
  // const images = listProduct.images;
  // images.push(result.uri);
  setListProduct({ ...listProduct });
  return;
};
```

Comment: Your `useListProductContext ` may be violating the rules of hooks, as React sees the `use` qualifier to validate the rules of hooks.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: @TR3 Decided to remove the world "use" and its working normally. I did not know about this rule as in another project just working with a user token produced no problems. I had it as useUser. If possible, please reply as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you

Comment: happy to assist, an easy "gotcha" to miss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useListProductContext`  is violating the rules of hooks, as React sees the `use` qualifier to validate the rules of hooks.

[Rules of Hooks](http://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

[Using a Custom Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook)

"Do I have to name my custom Hooks starting with “use”? Please do. This convention is very important. *Without it, we wouldn’t be able to **automatically** check for violations of rules of Hooks* because we couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to Hooks inside of it."

Comment: Where in that link does it say variables cannot be prefixed with `use`? That should be included with your answer

Comment: fixed...good to go

Comment: There's a chance he could use 

`const useListProductContext => useContext(ProductListContext);` and be just fine